# MongoDB, there is no info online about transactions and read operations interaction

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions, nosql

I'm trying to get the full picture...
When I create a session, I know all write operations that are associated with this session will either succeed together or roll back together.

I didn't find any official mongo documentation that explains what transactions lock exactly and when does the lock occur during the lifetime of the transaction (by lock I refer to both pessimistic lock or optimistic lock)

[post here seems](https://jimmybogard.com/document-level-pessimistic-concurrency-in-mongodb-now-with-intent-locks/) to be based on the assumption that a lock on a document starts after it's been updated and released at the end of the session.

But does the document even needs to lock? Does it indeed lock in that instant? Where can I find documentation on that?

That means that if I do

```ts
const person = await findOne({ id },{ session })
const updatedPerson = await updateOne({ id },{ person },{ session , new: true})
```

There is absolutely no meaning for `session` being on `findOne`? Because the specific `person` document doesn't get locked?

So if between me finding the person and updating the person, some other request have updated `Person`, `updatedPerson` could actually be different than `person`, is that correct? There is no mongoDB built in way with sessions to ensure `person` will be locked? ( I know there is a schema option for `optimisticConcurrency`, but I want to understand sessions, and also this option seems to be limited to only throwing an error instead of retrying which seems a bit odd considering usually the behavior you want with optimisticConcurrency is to retry or atleast have the option to)

If that's correct, then the only reason for `session` to be on strictly `read` operations would be to be able to view `write` results that are part of the session.

```ts
const updatedPerson = await updateOne({ id },{ field1: 'changed' },{ session , new: true})
const person = await findOne({ id} ,{ session })
```

Associating `person` with `session` here lets me view the `updatedPerson` post update.

Am I correct in my understanding? If so, that leads me to the next question, specifically on mongoose with `.save()`. According to [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#atomic-updates)

> For example, if you're using save() to update a document, the document can change
> in MongoDB in between when you load the document using findOne() and when you
> save the document using save() as show below. For many use cases, the save() race
> condition is a non-issue. But you can work around it with findOneAndUpdate() (**or
> transactions**) if you need to.

Which raises my question, how can you fix `save()` race condition with transactions considering transactions do not lock read documents?

Comment: You are asking too many things for a single question, even though I can understand your doubts because the documentation is definitely lacking. You can find something useful [here](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/tree/main/doc) if you want the big picture. I suggest you to edit the question with a more specific question if something is still unclear afterwards.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara Thanks! Even though it didn't answer my question, or atleast I couldn't infer the answer from the info provided there, it did provide me much insight on what's going on behind the scenes and I'll definitely go back to this resource many times, it's a very good one.

Comment: Happy to know you found it useful :) I forgot to tell you, but there are some [tests](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/blob/main/test/transaction.test.js) too that help to fully understand `WriteConflict`s in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some manual testings using `await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 5000));` and updating the document while a session is ongoing on it to observe its behavior.

My findings are as follows:

In this example:

```ts
const person = await findOne({ id },{ session })
const updatedPerson = await updateOne({ id },{ $set: { ...person } },{ session , new: true})
```

There **is** meaning for the `session` on `findOne`, even though the `findOne` operation doesn't lock the document, it causes `updateOne` to fail and abort the transaction **if** the document that was fetched by `findOne` , in our case `person`, was changed by something that is not part of the transaction.

That means you can trust that `updatedPerson` will be `person` because `person` is part of the session. This answer renders the rest of my question irrelevant.